# Incorrect result with MySQL secondary index on temp table with MyISAM engine

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I am using MySql 5.7 in Amazon RDS (Aurora).  The issue is with a secondary index on a temporary table (used as part of a stored procedure):

```
create temporary table tmpDemo (
 c1 varchar(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(c1), 
 c2 varchar(100) NOT NULL,...     
) Engine=MyIsam;
-- ... insert data into tmpDemo
  select c1,c2 from tmpDemo;      
  create index ix_secondary on tmpDemo(c2) USING BTREE;      
  select c1,c2 from tmpDemo;
```

On the last select, the data in column C1 is duplicated.  It's as if the secondary index remove the uniqueness constraint of the primary key:

```
11237357    00
11237357    00
11237357    00
```

The following small program recreates the problem.  If you wonder why I am using MyISAM and not InnoDB, it is because this is a read-only cluster on AWS Aurora DB and so I have no choice.  I do not know if this happens with a stand-alone MySQL instance.

```
drop procedure if exists showIxBug;
DELIMITER $$
create procedure showIxBug()
BEGIN
drop temporary table if exists tmpDemo;

create temporary table tmpDemo (
 c1 varchar(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(c1), 
 c2 varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 c3 int,
 c4 datetime NOT NULL
) Engine=MyIsam;

set @i=0;
  WHILE @i < 10000 DO
    set @seed = FLOOR(RAND()*12121212);
    set @c1 = convert(@seed,char);
    set @c2 = convert(@seed % 100,char);
    INSERT INTO  tmpDemo VALUES (
    @c1,concat(@c2,@c2),@seed,
    utc_timestamp()
        ) on duplicate key update c3=100;
    SET @i = @i + 1;
  END WHILE;

  select c1,c2 from tmpDemo;

  create index ix_secondary on tmpDemo(c2) USING BTREE;

  select c1,c2 from tmpDemo;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
call showIxBug();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, I got the answer from AWS technical support, and I'm sharing it here in case anyone else runs into it (and does not pay for the extra support).  This is a bug in AWS Aurora, not so much with MySql as I understand it.

> > Doing further research, I was able to find a fix released for 2.03.3 "Fixed a wrong result issue with MyISAM temporary tables where only indexed columns are accessed." [1] In order to verify whether it is something related to this fix I have already reached to the internal team to take a further look at it.

I have since upgraded to 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2 and I can verify that the issue is fixed.  Initial Aurora version was 5.7.12.  (Aurora numbering scheme seems like complete nonsense to me - was not obvious that 5.7.12 is << 5.7.mysql_aurora.1.07.2))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is going on there, but [Aurora doesn't support MyISAM at all](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/), according to official documentation.

Comment: Indeed.  But they mean for permanent tables.  MyISAM is the default table type for temporary tables on readers and InnoDB is not available.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61734681/mysql-amazon-rds-innodb-feature-disabled-error-from-application

Comment: I suspect you will find that you are way off the supported path here. It's probably a bug outside of scope of normal operation.

Comment: What part of my question is 'outside the scope of normal operation'?  Standard procedures and tables with more than one index.  Seems pretty normal to me.

Comment: The part where you are using MyISAM. From the page I linked above: "Certain MySQL features like the MyISAM storage engine are not available with Amazon Aurora." According to that, the fact that MyISAM is available at all is unexpected.